# Caliburn Micro, Bindable AppBar problems with pivot

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, windows-phone-8, caliburn.micro

Im writing my first WP app with caliburn micro and try to use [Caliburn Bindable AppBar](https://github.com/kamranayub/CaliburnBindableAppBar). My app has basically only one pivot page (Conductor) with multiple pivot items (views).

My goal is to use same app bar with all these pivot items, if I add the app bar to conductor page, it disappears when I change pivot item. If I add app bar to every pivot items it works yes, but the button "jumps up" every time when I change the pivot item as the app bar is created every time again.

How should I use the caliburn bindable app bar to include same app bar to each pivot items?

Currently my implementation is straight from example:

```
// View
<bindableAppBar:BindableAppBar x:Name="AppBar">
    <bindableAppBar:BindableAppBarButton
                    x:Name="Star"
                    Text="Star"                            
                    IconUri="/Icons/ApplicationBar.Star.Add.png"/>
</bindableAppBar:BindableAppBar>



// Conductorpage
AppBarConductor.Mixin(this);
```

Comment: Where exactly do you put the bindableAppBar? Before </PivotItem> or before </Pivot>?

Comment: When I tried to put app bar to conductor page, I put the bindableAppBar after the pivot control. So after </pivot>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing `AppBarConductor.Mixin(this);` It is only there to enable different appbars for each Pivot item

Comment: Thanks, actually find out that Caliburn has its own AppBarButton implementation so I switched to that one.